# Can a character style be applied programmatically to a string before it is written to the Word document with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting, string-formatting

I am grabbing some data from an Excel sheet and populating it into a Word template. I'm hoping that I can assign some of the Document's character styles to sub strings that will be added to the Document as the string is built up rather than having add the string to the Document and then select each string individually to apply the appropriate style.

Right now, I'm concatenating a few strings and adding them to a text box in the document like this:

`ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 7").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = str1 & " " & str2 & ", " & str3`

This runs in a loop and prints several of these lines to the Document. I would, however, like to assign/apply a different character style to `str1`, `str2` and `str3` on each line as it's being written to the Document. Something like:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 7").TextFrame.TextRange.Text =
    str1.applyStyle("charStyle1") & 
    " " & 
    str2.applyStyle("charStyle2") & 
    ", " &
    str3.applyStyle("charStyle3")
```

I realize there is no `String.applyStyle()` method, but is there anything that can be done that comes close to this functionality or does the string have to be written to the Document first and then loaded into a `Range` object and THEN have its `Style` property set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 7").TextFrame.TextRange
  .Style = "Style1"
  .Text = str1 & " "
  .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Style = "Style2"
  .Text = str2 & ", "
  .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Style = "Style3"
  .Text = str3
End With
```

Comment: Yes, Collapse() did the trick. I had to modify 1 thing tho... since all that was being run in a loop, I had to make sure to use `.Collapse wdCollapseEnd` for ALL 3 Strings (instead of just the last 2) after the first iteration of the loop.