# In-line insertions of preformatted strings

Tags: vba, ms-word

while working on the below macro to populate an MS word table, I had a cell in mind with two statements, one is bold text while the other isn't, below is the way I approached it. I'm sure there is a smarter, more of an in-line way, to implement fast formatted strings insertions. Also, the below implementation doesn't work Any thoughts?

```
For n = 1 To nCount
    With oTable.Rows(n + 1)
        'Page number
        .Cells(1).Range.Text = _
            oDoc.Comments(n).Scope.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        .
        .
        .
        .Cells(3).Range.Text = "First Statement: "
        .Cells(3).Range.Select
        With .Cells(3).Range
            .Bold = True
        End With
        .Cells(3).Range.Bold = False
        .Cells(3).Range.InsertAfter ("Second Statement")
    End With
Next n
```

Comment: Your code first bolds the entire Cells(6) range then, having added the text, unbolds the entire cell range; you may as well have started off with just the unbolding and omit the second one. Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, now further troubles, I intend to add two statements in the same cell; one that is bold and the other isn't. How can that be done?

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186012/can-a-character-style-be-applied-programmatically-to-a-string-before-it-is-writt

Comment: Not what I intend. I've updated the code up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Rng As Range
For n = 1 To nCount
    With oTable.Rows(n + 1)
        'Page number
        .Cells(1).Range.Text = _
            oDoc.Comments(n).Scope.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        '
        '

    Set Rng = .Cells(3).Range
    With Rng
      .End = .End - 1
      .Text = "First Statement: "
      .Font.Bold = True
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Text = "Second Statement"
      .Font.Bold = False
    End With
Next n
```

Comment: Thanks macropod. However, It still doesn't bold out the text as the ".Font.Bold = False" applies to the whole range.

Comment: There was a typo in the 'Collapse' line. Try it now

Comment: I highly appreciate the effort macropod but it's still not working. I had a way around it though but not really an optimised solution, after the table creation I execute a find and replace with bold method

Comment: Dim oRng As Word.Range
        Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
        With oRng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "1st Cycle:"
            '.Replacement.Text = "1st Cycle:"
            .MatchWildcards = False
        .Format = True
        '.Font.Bold = True
        '.Replacement.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

Comment: Works flawlessly! Good stuff Macropod!